# Load front-page.php from subfolder

Tags: frontpage, template-hierarchy

My `front-page.php` works fine in the WordPress root folder. But I would like to put it in the *page-templates* subfolder.

How do I make it load from there?

Comment: It's supposed to be in the root folder, why do you want it in the page templates subfolder? It isn't a page (or a page template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `frontpage_template` filter to adjust where your template should be loaded from

```
add_filter( 'frontpage_template', function ( $template )
{
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'page-templates/front-page.php' );

    if ( !$locate_template )
        return $template;

    return $locate_template;
});
```

Comment: it's not loading. I put the code in my functions.php. the path is correct, do I have to adjust anything else?

Comment: @MrKainig,  you went in the backend(Admin) to `Settings/Permalinks` and clicked `Save Changes` ?

Comment: I just did that. Nothing changes

Comment: @MrKainig Had my filter name wrong, please see updated code

Comment: /Off topic probably but, @PieterGoosen, just curious here, why using an anonymous function. I am really interested in this, about the 'when to use this smart way' and when it is 'not done'.

Comment: @Charles Lazyness, that is all. Closures are quicker to code and does not require that a unique function name. On stack like these, closures are easier to post and also avoid function name conflict. Closures do have one big set back though which you should always consider before using them, they cannot be removed with simple `remove_action()` and `remove_filter()` calls.