# How to include a new file in theme

Tags: themes

I have added a folder in my `themes` Folder.  In that folder I have added a file using `a` tag.

Now when I open that file, it gives me no header no footer.
I tried including the header and footer files.

It gives me this error

> Call to undefined function get_template_directory_uri()

Please tell what to include in this file, or rather where to include this file to collaborate with the theme , and so that I can use WordPress functions.

**Further Info**
The file I am adding is a php file.Right now its nothing to do with template. How to make it follow a page template ?? I just added a code in that file which is

```
<?php echo "hi";?>
```

Output is I get `hi` without header and footer.But I want header and footer too.

Comment: we need more information. What kind of file are you trying to add and what are you trying to do? Is it an entire new template? Is it a template part that you are trying to incorporate? Check the Theme Development section of the codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Theme php files don't get accessed via URL directly. You load WordPress objects- a page, a post, an archive, etc., and those are mapped to template files.

Comment: @RayMitchell : i added more info

Comment: @YoYo If you are looking to add content and have it be displayed as part of "the page" along with the header and footer, your code will either have to be a template part, be content in a new and unique post type (to be called up called up as part of the loop) or be content as part of an existing post type (post, page, aside etc.). Milo's comment alludes to this.  See - https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look in the [twentysixteen theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/).

Line 18/19 (*inside [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)*) of `single.php` shows actualy all you need/want to know, it uses:
[`get_template_part( $slug, $name );`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

- `// Include the single post content template`
- `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );`

That means actualy for WP:

- Get a (*partial*) [template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) for a (*in this case*) [single post](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post).
- Look in the folder (*from within your `theme` directory*)
  `template-parts` for a file which has the name
  `content-single.php`.
- 'Grab' what is in it (lets say `<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>`) and display - Hello World - as `content` for that `post`.

This way it already has the `header` and `footer` as you want it/as (*imho*) should be done.
<strike>*There are other ways to load -templates- (through a [`function`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/217622/15605)) but that was not the question here.*</strike>

Note: You can do this also with `page.php` / `taxonomy.php` / `archive.php` / `category.php` etc.

> See the codex for: [Theme development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
>   See the codex for: [Linking to Core Theme Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/linking-theme-files-directories/)

I hope this explains (*although in a digest size*) the basics of how you can use `get_template_part`.